# Central position Images with CSS and HTML in django project

Tags: python, html, css, django

Working on landing page Django, trying to centre images with css, but it doesn't work for me, Im stucked, cant find any asnwer on the internet.
My first project for portfolio.
Please help me with this question, will be very glad.
Thank you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="eng">

<! --looks good on mobile devices-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Main page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header-text" style="color:white">Follow me:</div>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/kseniia_ifbblatvia" class="header-link1">Instagram</a>
        <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@super_zav" class="header-link2">TikTok</a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009190064504" class="header-link3">Facebook</a>

        <div class="images">
            <img src="{% static 'tiktok.png' %}" width="100" height="100" alt="tiktok image" class="tiktok">
            <img src="{% static 'insta.png' %}" width="100" height="100" alt="instagram image" class="instagram">
            <img src="{% static 'facebook.png' %}" width="100" height="100" alt="facebook image" class="facebook">
        </div>
    </header>
        <h1>Personal training and nutrition plan</h1>
        <p>Text about it</p>
</body>

</html>
```

And CSS:

```
body{
   background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534258936925-c58bed479fcb?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=889&q=80) no-repeat center center fixed;
   background-size: cover;
}

.tiktok {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 border: 2px solid white;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-right: 1070px;
}
.instagram {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 border: 2px solid white;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-right: 890px;
}
.facebook {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 border: 2px solid white;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-right: 690px;
}

}
.header-text {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;

}

.header-link1{
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.header-link2{
  height: 40%;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.header-link3{
  height: 40%;
  width: 120%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
color: white;
}
```

Right now it looks like this (attached image of the page):
[landingpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTolo.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tips:This question only contains css & html.
You should not use margin-right
use flex ,it can auto center
you can use DevTools find image's real size
For example [CodePen](https://codepen.io/xiao-e-yun/pen/wvdvoBz)

html:

```
<div class="images">
  <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://xiaoeyun.me/resources/img/avatar.png')">
    <a>hi</a>
  </div>
  <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://xiaoeyun.me/resources/img/avatar.png')">
    <a>hi</a>
  </div>
  <div class="image" style="background-image:url('https://xiaoeyun.me/resources/img/avatar.png')">
    <a>hi</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.images {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.image > a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to center your images wrapper, so that the images are center focused, if this is the case then try this:

```
.images{ display:flex; justify-content:center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in your example screenshot, try something like this if you want space in between:

```
.images{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  max-width:60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```